# Cannot Install Wine32 unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies

Hi I am trying install wine32 and it is complaining of unmet dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdevmapper1.02.1 : Depends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: dmsetup (>= 2:1.02.175-2.1ubuntu3~)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

But when I try to install libselinux1 using "sudo apt install libselinux1" is says I already have a version the meets the requirements:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libselinux1 is already the newest version (3.1-3build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

So I dont understand why wine32 wont install if the required package is already > then what it is asking for. Any Ideas?

EDIT:

I previously ran sudo dpkg `--add-architecture i386`

```
$ dpkg   --print-architecture
amd64
```

```
$ dpkg   --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

Installation still fails in the same exact way

Comment: Try installing the 32 bit version, libselinux1:i386

Comment: Have you installed i386 architecture? Run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` I hope this helps.  This will make it so that you can install and run 32-bit programs on 64-bit Linux systems.

Comment: @ubfan1 He is installing the 32-bit version, hence the name Wine32. Wine32 is for 32-bit systems.

Comment: @Jeff see edit, tried what you suggested

Comment: what Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @ThomasWard 

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 21.10
Release: 21.10
Codename: impish

Comment: @IsaacMontaine Did you download Wine from the official website?

Comment: @Jeff yes I followed the instructions here https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: I have filed an Ubuntu bug. Anyone having this problem, if they have a Launchpad account, can go to the bug and click the option "this affects me too". This will help the bug to gain some attention.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/2000832