# Trouble with wine32

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, 64-bit, 22.04

I installed wine64 using sudo apt-get install wine64 and when I run wine --version it sends in the terminal that I need wine32 because it's missing. I do sudo apt-get install wine32 as the message suggests and it sends this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
coreutils : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
dpkg : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
findutils : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
grep : PreDepends: libpcre3 but it is not installable
init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
login : PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
     PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
sed : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed but it is not going to be installed or
                    grub-efi-arm64-signed but it is not installable
           Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
tar : PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
util-linux : PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.37.2) but it is not going to be installed
          PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 3.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held 
packages.
```

How can I fix this? (using version 22.04.)

Comment: Did you add any ppa/external repository for wine?

Comment: The edit to the question that points to another question is a red herring. It is irrelevant. I have the same problem and I have no broken packages.

Comment: Other people experiencing related problems are here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410718/cannot-install-wine32-in-jammy-22-04 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434526/jammy-22-04-wont-install-wine32 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403520/cannot-install-wine32-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I have filed an Ubuntu bug. Anyone having this problem, if they have a Launchpad account, can go to the bug and click the option "this affects me too". This will help the bug to gain some attention.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/2000832