# Jammy (22.04) won't install wine32

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

Been trying to install wine32 for days without luck.

This is my output:

```
root@nico-laptop:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatk-wrapper-java-jni : Depends: libatk-wrapper-java (>= 0.38.0-5build1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1 : Depends: libglx0 (= 1.4.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

When I try to install those missing dependencies using apt, it says they're already there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please could you edit your question to add some more information re what you have done so far (how did you try to install, what is your hardware, has it worked before, etc.) - someone will likely try to help with that information. Thank you!

Comment: This is a recurrent problem on 22.04. I have it too. Here are other people asking about being unable to install `wine32`:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421863/trouble-with-wine32 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410718/cannot-install-wine32-in-jammy-22-04 ; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403520/cannot-install-wine32-unmet-dependencies

Comment: I have filed an Ubuntu bug. Anyone having this problem, if they have a Launchpad account, can go to the bug and click the option "this affects me too". This will help the bug to gain some attention.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/2000832